# Showing login user info in all views in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have  a website with auth for some pages. How can I show the logged in user in the header name and thumb)  without sending the info in each controller to each view I show?

P.S: I do not want to show only trivial data about the user form Auth::user() For example I want to show also a thumb or somethign that is not strictly on the `User` model. Like time when was logged on. Or next billing date.

Answer (score 1):

you can have the full information about logged in user in laravel by

```
$user = Auth::user()
```

it will return a user to you of the User the model .

for getting certain information of user you can use

```
$user->username;
```

or sth like

```
$user->billing
```

and I also have to tell that you can have information which is on your database;

I think this may help you .

```
dd($user)
```

I hope got I undrestood your problem corectly.

Comment: And what about the time i do not want data only from the `User` model? See update PS